# cgridview not filtering at all

Tags: yii, cgridview

I googled everywhere and I just can't see what else am I missing? The filter on the top doesn't do anything. I think this is the default from crud, not sure. What else am I missing here though?

controller:

```
$model=new Product('search');
$model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
if(isset($_GET['Product']))
    $model->attributes=$_GET['Product'];

$this->render('view',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

model rules:

```
array('product_id, product_name,product_price, product_status, 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
```

and view:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'product-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'product_id',
        'product_name',
        'product_price',
        'product_status',

        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

model search, pretty much the default

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('product_id',$this->product_id);
    $criteria->compare('product_name',$this->product_name);
    $criteria->compare('product_price',$this->product_price);
    $criteria->compare('product_status',$this->product_status);     
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
```

js

```
jQuery(function($) {

$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#product-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});

jQuery(document).on('click','#product-grid a.delete',function() {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) return false;
    var th = this,
        afterDelete = function(){};
    jQuery('#product-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        type: 'POST',
        url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#product-grid').yiiGridView('update');
            afterDelete(th, true, data);
        },
        error: function(XHR) {
            return afterDelete(th, false, XHR);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
jQuery('#product-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['product-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pager','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'items','selectableRows':1,'enableHistory':false,'updateSelector':'{page}, {sort}','filterSelector':'{filter}','pageVar':'Product_page'});
            App.setMainPage(true);
            App.init();
            App.setTableDetails(jsonDashboard);
});
/*]]>*/
```

Comment: As I see no other source for an error: Could you c&p the `search()` method of your model as well?

Comment: added the search, it's just the default whatever yii generated.

Comment: I don't get it. Everything is looking fine. Is the view you are invoking with `$this->render('view',...)` really the intended one? i.e. it's not "view" where you wanted "index"?

Comment: yes that's correct. :/

Answer (score 0):

While running a CGridView in yii it generates a jquery automatically at the bottom of the page for proper working of CGridView copy that script from browser it will not show you in the view so copy it from browser and paste it here. That jquery may be making some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting this using firebug and check whether jquery is working or not.